# How to represent su(2) Higgs triplet in 2x2 matrix form?

Tags: higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

How to represent su(2) triplet(say Higgs triplet) in the 2x2 matrix form? 
Please provide the mathematical reason behind it.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Pauli vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Pauli_vector) in the rotation group?

Comment: yeah I am familiar with that.